# Risks while running an Apache web server on a centos 8 machine

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, centos

I am trying to install Apache webserver on a Centos 8 machine using this tutorial: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-apache-centos-8

The network inside my room has the following configuration: internet from the service provider connects to a router (with wired+wireless outputs) provided by the service provider -> wired output from the service provider router connects to a hub (or I guess it's a switch?) -> the hub connects to various other workstations (windows computers + 1 centos 8 server installation)

All of the computers in my network use DHCP and have an address in the range 192.168.xx.xx

If I install Apache web server in the CentOS computer using the tutorial above, will I be exposing this computer to any risks? Assume there are no problems within my network (no computers have virus or are hacked, no other bad actors within the room network, etc). Will the webpages in the CentOS computer be visible to anything outside my network? Will anything outside my network be able to send or receiving anything from this CentOS computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All of the computers in my network use DHCP and have an address in the
>   range 192.168.xx.xx

You’ve indicated that all of your devices are using a private, non-routable IP address. As a result, your router/gateway needs to perform NAT translations to provide public internet access to your devices. By its very nature, this type of NAT prevents anything on the internet from initiating communication with a private device on your network.

So, the answer is NO. Your server will not be exposed to the internet unless you specifically configure port forwarding on your router to do so.

Comment: Will the same principle apply to ftp and file servers? As long as I don't reconfigure my router, can I stop worrying about this server computer getting attacked in any way from the internet?

Comment: Yes. Every device on a private network (behind NAT) is safe from “direct” attacks from the internet assuming there is no port forwarding. As you mentioned, there are still other threats like other infected devices on your private network.

Comment: Note that @Appleoddity advice is - practically speaking - correct for ipv4. It does not necessarily hold true for IPV6